# I deleted an important contact on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

I deleted a contact on my old inactivated iPhone 4.  This to my surprise deleted to from my new iPhone 5s.  Is there anyway to retrieve it?  I realize now my new iMac, new iPhone and old one are all synced from the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your restore options in iTunes, there are usually a couple of previous backup versions. You could make a new backup, try restoring an older one, save the contact you want on another system then restore your new backup.

Comment: For the future: Just create a local backup of your contacts, notes, etc. on you Mac or iPhone from time to time. Accidentally removed data is much easier to restore that way.